# 8 Queens Java Recursion

Tags: java

I am practicing for my final for my AP Computer Science class. Anyways, I have just learned recursion and I need help simplifying several methods into one for the 8 queens problem.

I am needing to combine the rowOne-rowEight methods into one method in itself. The program works and prints all 92 solutions, but it just needs simplified..

```
public class NonAttacking
{
    private static int [][] board = new int[8][8];

    private static int count = 0;

    public void rowOne(int y)
    {
        int x = 0;

        if(onBoard(x, y) != -1)     
        {
            if(validMove(x, y) == 0) //if the move is valid (0) then it puts a 1 at those coordinates and moves on to the next method (RowTwo)
            {
                board[x][y] = 1;
                rowTwo(0);
            }

            board[x][y] = 0;
            rowOne(y + 1);
        }
    }

    public void rowTwo(int col)
    {
        int x = 1;
        if(onBoard(x, col) != -1)       
        {
            if(validMove(x, col) == 0)
            {
                board[x][col] = 1;
                rowThree(0);
            }

            board[x][col] = 0;
            rowTwo(col + 1);

        }
    }

    public void rowThree(int col)
    {
        int x = 2;
        if(onBoard(x, col) != -1)       
        {
            if(validMove(x, col) == 0)
            {
                board[x][col] = 1;
                rowFour(0);
            }

            board[x][col] = 0;
            rowThree(col + 1);
        }
    }

    public void rowFour(int col) 
    {
        int x = 3;      
        if(onBoard(x, col) != -1)       
        {
            if(validMove(x, col) == 0)
            {
                board[x][col] = 1;
                rowFive(0);
            }

            board[x][col] = 0;
            rowFour(col + 1);
        }
    }

    public void rowFive(int col)
    {
        int x = 4;  
        if(onBoard(x, col) != -1)       
        {
            if(validMove(x, col) == 0)
            {
                board[x][col] = 1;
                rowSix(0);
            }
            board[x][col] = 0;
            rowFive(col + 1);
        }
    }

    public void rowSix(int col)
    {
        int row = 5;



        if(onBoard(row, col) != -1)     
        {
            if(validMove(row, col) == 0)
            {
                board[row][col] = 1;
                rowSeven(0);
            }

            board[row][col] = 0;
            rowSix(col + 1);
        }
    }

    public void rowSeven(int col)
    {
        int row = 6;    
        if(onBoard(row, col) != -1)     
        {
            if(validMove(row, col) == 0)
            {
                board[row][col] = 1;
                rowEight(0);
            }

            board[row][col] = 0;
            rowSeven(col + 1);
        }
    }

    public void rowEight(int col)
    {       
        int row = 7;    
        if(onBoard(row, col) != -1)     
        {
            if(validMove(row, col) == 0)
            {
                board[row][col] = 1;
                count++;

                System.out.println(toString());
            }

            board[row][col] = 0;
            rowEight(col + 1);
        }
    }


    public static int validMove(int row, int col)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            if(onBoard(row, i) == 1) //checks side to side
            {
                return -1;
            }
            if(onBoard(i, col) == 1) //checks up and down
            {
                return -1;
            }

        }

        //Check Diagonally
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            if(onBoard(row - i, col - i) == 1) //checks up and left
            {
                return -1;
            }

            if(onBoard(row - i, col + i) == 1) //checks up and right
            {
                return -1;
            }
            if(onBoard(row + i, col - i) == 1) //checks down and left
            {
                return -1;
            }
            if(onBoard(row + i, col + i) == 1) //checks down and right
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }


        return 0; //if it works
    }

    public static int onBoard(int row, int col)
    {
        if(row < 0 || col < 0 || row > 7 || col > 7) //checks if it is valid on the board
        {
            return -1;
        }


        return board[row][col]; //returns what the value is at the valid point
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        System.out.println(print());
        String ans = "Solution: ";
        ans += count;

        return ans;
    }

    public static String print()
    {
        String sol = "Solution: " + count;
        String result = "\n";
        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++)
        {
            for(int column = 0; column < board[row].length; column++)
            {
                result += board[row][column] + "\t";
            }
            result += "\n";
        }
        return result;

    }
}
```

Driver:
`

```
public class Driver 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        NonAttacking queen = new NonAttacking();

        queen.rowOne(0);

        System.out.println(queen.print());
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you are looking to do is replace the 8 methods with one method then the following should do as required, using rowN(0, 0) to begin.

```
public void rowN(int n, int y)
{
    if(onBoard(n, y) != -1)     
    {
        if(validMove(n, y) == 0) //if the move is valid (0) then it puts a 1 at those coordinates and moves on to the next method (RowTwo)
        {
            board[n][y] = 1;
            if(n<7) {
                rowN(n+1, 0);
            }
            else {
                count++;
                System.out.println(toString());
            }
        }

        board[n][y] = 0;
        rowN(n, y + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the rowOne method still being called at the bottom?  Do I just name that rowN?

Comment: Any place you call `rowOne`, you call `rowN` and use an `n` parameter of 1.

Comment: I did rename the line of code `rowOne(y+1);` to `rowN(x, (y+1));` and it produced just this output: `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 `

Comment: My bad I've edited the answer, you should now need to start it with rowN(0, 0) instead. Hopefully, that should have fixed it.

Comment: You're mixing use of `x` and `n` in this answer, but it seems to work so long as you change them all to the same variable.

Comment: Good spot I'll fix that, cheers